# Checking workflows behind case reassignment history?

Tags: workflow, case

I have a certain case type that is initially being assigned correctly, but then gets reassigned to the wrong team. Is there a way to see which rule tripped each line in the case history? Or otherwise troubleshoot this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can discover this in the debug logs. Look for WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN; WF_RULE_ENTRY_ORDER; WF_RULE_FILTER; WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE; WF_CRITERIA_END - The rule that ends with true is the one that fired.

Comment: Looks like there are no debug logs in my org.

Comment: @Akor look at the case history and see which user is related to the assignment then monitor that user in debug and replicate the issue. Then you should see a debug log for that user.

Comment: Seeing the debug log but the issue is that the case is being assigned to a queue, which isn't a user I can monitor. Is there a way to implement a rule in my existing workflow that says to stop changing owners after this rule is triggered?

Comment: @AKor, I believe even though it is being assigned to a queue there should be a user associated with that action. Did you look at the Case history related list to see what user is associated with the change?